# Mockito using spy object running actual code hence giving error

Tags: jax-rs, mockito

I have this bunch of code. First is a test class method testEndPoint(), I have also included the class to be tested EndPointClass.

When I run this testmethod, it tries to run the actual send http Call method instead of mocking or a dummy call, hence it gives a 500 not found error.
I know somewhere the code needs to be corrected not sure where.
Here's the code

```
public void testEndPoint(){
    OutputObject output = new OutputObject();
    EndPointClass epClass = new EndPointClass();
    EndPointClass epClassSpy = Mockito.spy(epClass);

    List<JacksonJsonProvider> providers = new ArrayList<JacksonJsonProvider>();
    providers.add(mockCustomJacksonProvider);

    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://example.org/home",providers);
    WebClientWrapper webClientWrapper = new WebClientWrapper(client);
    WebClientWrapper spyWebClient = Mockito.spy(webClientWrapper); 
    Mockito.when(spyWebClient.invoke(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(Object.class),Mockito.eq(OutputObject.class))).thenReturn(output);
    Mockito.when(epClassSpy.webCall(spyWebClient)).thenReturn(output);
    OutputObject response = epClassSpy.sendRequest("ABC", "ABCToken");      
}

public class EndPointClass{
    public OutputObject sendRequest(String input, String authToken){

        List<JacksonJsonProvider> providers = new ArrayList<JacksonJsonProvider>();
        providers.add(downloadsJacksonProvider);
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(olsDownloadUrl+path, providers);
        if (null == timeOut) {
            timeOut = 60000;
        }

        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) WebClient.getConfig(client).getConduit();   
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy(); 
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(0); 
        httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(timeOut);   
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        client.type("application/json");
        client.accept("application/json");
        client.header("x-auth-Token", authToken);
        client.query("input", input);

        OutputObject output = null;
        WebClientWrapper clientWrapper = new WebClientWrapper(client);
        output = webCall(clientWrapper);
        return output;
    }

    public OutputObject webCall(WebClientWrapper clientWrapper) {
        return clientWrapper.invoke(HttpMethod.GET, null, OutputObject.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy)

> Important gotcha on spying real objects!
>       Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use when(Object) for stubbing spies. Therefore when using spies please consider doReturn|Answer|Throw() family of methods for stubbing. Example:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
List spy = spy(list);

//Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws ndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)
when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");

//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing
doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```

So just change your Mockito.when(...) to Mockito.doReturn(...) that should do the trick.

Comment: I replace the lines with 'when' with these, <i>   Mockito.doReturn(output).when(epClassSpy).webCall(webClientWrapper);
  
    Mockito.doReturn(output).when(spyWebClient).invoke(Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(Object.class),Mockito.eq(Output.class));
</i> Still get the same output

Comment: Didn't look right into your code, sorry. In sendRequest you create a new instance of WebClient that is wrapped in a new WebClientWrapper which then is passed to your spy Method. So Mockito.doReturn(output).when(epClassSpy).webCall(**webClientWrapper**); is never hit as you call the method with another instance.

Comment: Actually with this change the code worked in Eclipse using testng plugin but mvn test in command prompt gives another exception

Comment: Problem is with WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://example.com/home",providers);WebClientWrapper webClientWrapper = new WebClientWrapper(client);WebClientWrapper spyWebClient = Mockito.spy(webClientWrapper); 
 It gives java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.createWebClient(JAXRSClientFactoryBean.java:233) org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:178) at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.create(WebClient.java:138)

Comment: When it's working in Eclipse but not in maven build you should check your Eclipse buildpath with your maven dependencies.

Comment: Will have to find, what's wrong. But the project was imported after mvn eclipse:eclipse itself, so not sure whats going on.